# Is linux mount propagation asynchronous to the mount call?

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel, namespace, bind-mount

I have two processes in different mount namespaces. They have a shared directory bind mounted to `/mnt/share`. The "master" uses `MS_SHARED` propagation for the mount, while the "slave" uses `MS_SLAVE`.

The master process sets up a bind mount that is a child of `/mnt/share`, let's say `/mnt/share/sub`, and then creates a file `/mnt/share/sub-ready`. The slave process has an inotify watch on `/mnt/share` which hears the create event for `sub-ready` and immediately looks for `/mnt/share/sub/sub-file`, which it does not find. It is visible to the slave process a fraction of a second later, but not immediately after the `sub-ready` file is created.

Could it be that while mount certainly returns only after the mount point is created in the caller's namespace, it can return before it has been propagated to other namespaces? Or is there a bug in the plan I have described?